# Bootstrap & Angular css issue

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I built a small mobile website with `AngularJS` & `Bootstrap`. Please see http://www.quaaoutlodge.com/mobile/
Now I would like to move the text into the center of the `<li` list items but when I add a `padding-bottom` or `margin-bottom` to the `#desc` element, the text doesn't move up at all but the reserved space seems to just go across the `<li` border. Why is this? How do I change this so that I achieve above described effect?

Thank you!

**edit 1**
I changed the `<span` style from `id` to `class`, added `display: inline-block;` and `padding-bottom: 10px;`and the padding gets applied right now but, how do I move the text up while the icon on the left stays so that they get aligned centred to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to fix the problem of having non-unique id elements on the page! You should probably be using a class for #desc, instead of an id.

In regards to the padding on the #desc span, you need to set the `display` style to inline-block, and then you should be able to use padding to affect the space around it.